# Query with many to many field value of a table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
      tag = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)



class Image(models.Model):
      image_name=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=False)
      image=models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
      tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

The view is like this:

```
class ImagePostAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,generics.ListAPIView):
     queryset = Image.objects.all()
     query = Tag.objects.all()
     serializer_class = imagesSerializer

     def get_queryset(self):
        tag_value = self.request.query_params.get('tags', None)

        if tag_value is not None:
          try:
             queryset=Image.objects.filter(tags=tag_value)
          except:
             pass
        return queryset
```

I am able filter the data using the tag_id but i want to filter using the tag value. 
My url look like this:

```
GET /images/?tags=banner
```

How to achieve this in Django ?

Comment: simple is change `queryset=Image.objects.filter(tags=tag_value)` to `queryset=Image.objects.filter(tags__tag=tag_value)`

Comment: Its working,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and fast solution is to change the url parameter to **`tags__tag`** instead of **`tags`** as,

```
GET /images/?tags__tag=banner
```

---

If you want more controll over the filtering parameters, use [**`django-filter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package.This section, [**`filterset_class`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class) showing a similar example related to your question